# Printing all paths in a matrix

Tags: c++, string, recursion, matrix

I am trying to print all the possible paths in a [matrix](/questions/tagged/matrix) (nXm) where right and down movements are allowed

```
int n,m;

int findWays(int x, int y, string str)
{
    int right,down;
    char *p ;
    if(x<=n && y<=m)
    {
        str +="(";
        itoa(x,p,10);
        str += p;
        str += ",";
        itoa(y,p,10);
        str += p;
        str +="),";
     //   cout<< "X : "<<x<<" Y : "<<y<<endl<<str<<endl;
        if(x==n && y==m)
        {
            cout<<"Path End : "<<str<<endl;
            return 1;
        }
     //   cout<<"Going Right : "<<str<<endl;
        right = findWays(x+1,y,str);
        //cout<<"Going Down : "<<str<<endl;
        down = findWays(x,y+1,str);
        return (right+down);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    int count;
    cout<< "Enter N and M: ";
    cin>>n>>m;
    cout<<"Paths :\n";
    count = findWays(1,1,str);
    cout<<" Total no of Paths : "<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

some how the string ig getting corrupted.

eg:
n=3,m=3

Path End : (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),

Path End : **1** ,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,2),(3,3),

Path End : **2** ,1),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),

Path End : **1** ,1),(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(3,3),

Path End : **2** ,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),

Path End : **2** ,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),

only the first two character, somehow, replaced by a count and rest of the string is good

I can use a integer array instead and print it. But I don't know how and why the string getting changed?

Comment: `char *p ; itoa(x,p,10);`,  no space for `p`.  Try `char p[50];`

Comment: Instead of (non-standard) `itoa`, use `std::to_string` (C++11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As point out by chux, you use an uninitialized value `p`,
I suggest to use `std::to_string` (C++11) instead of (non standard) `itoa` as follow:  https://ideone.com/h5hPj1

```
int findWays(int x, int y, std::string str)
{
    if (x <= n && y <= m)
    {
        str += "(";
        str += std::to_string(x);
        str += ", ";
        str += std::to_string(y);
        str +="), ";
        if (x == n && y == m)
        {
            std::cout << "Path End : " << str << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        int right = findWays(x + 1, y, str);
        int down = findWays(x, y + 1, str);
        return (right + down);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but any idea why string got corrupted?

Comment: p is used uninitialized, and may so corrupt memory.

Comment: Why there is a pattern in the corruption, that to same output no matter haw many time I run the code. If the corrupt string gives random output, I will settle with the uninitialized p but I think there is some thing else.

Answer (score 0):

`str += p;` when `p` is a `char*` ends up invoking the wrong overload - it assumes that `p` is a [pointer to the first element in a null-terminated array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B). Change it to

```
str += (*p);
```